# How to show two column data at the same line in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am created the js tree and my facing problem is how to show two column data at the same line in the array?

Below is my output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8jB5.png)

This my coding, my problem is how I can add $row['category'] at this `"text" => $row['name'],` line.

```html
<?php 
   $folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM folder_category where status=1");

   $folders_arr = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
      $parentid = $row['parentid'];
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $row['name'],  //how I can add $row['category'] at this same line.
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
      );
   }

   ?>

   <!-- Initialize jsTree -->
   <div id="folder_jstree" title="JTM"></div>
   <!-- Store folder list in JSON format -->
   <textarea style="" id='txt_folderjsondata'><?= json_encode($folders_arr) ?></textarea>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse($('#txt_folderjsondata').val());

   $('#folder_jstree').jstree({ 'core' : {
      'data' : folder_jsondata,
      'multiple': false
   } });

});

</script>
```

Then the output will like below the sample picture, so I want the $row['category'] put behind the $row['name'] at the same line:
[Output3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1YWU.png)

Below is my table info:
[Output 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE48e.png)

Hope someone can guide me solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the two strings.

```
[
    ...
    'text' => $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['category'],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Mr. Marcel, can I ask you 1 more question base on this question? Do you know how to make this $row['category'] value size become small a bit?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "value size become small a bit"? Do you want to shrink the font size of the category?